# Kivy "KeyError: " (I have made a minimal reproducible example )

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

### Note

This is not my code, I tried to create a minimal reproducible example.

### Code

This is a part of my python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from PIL import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
import threading


class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class GUI2App(App):
    remainingFolders=0
    totalFolders=0
    def update_progress(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(GUI2App.update_progress_after(self))
    def update_progress_after(self):
        print("running")
        print("Ids:\n",self.root.ids)
        loadingBar= self.root.ids['loadingBar']
        loadingBar.max=self.totalFolders
        loadingBar.value=self.remainingFolders

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Past Paper Question Search '
        return MyFloatLayout()
    def initConcatenate(self):
        p = threading.Thread(target=self.concatenate)
        p.start()
    def concatenate(self):
        totfolders=1
        for x in range(50):
            totfolders+=1     
        self.totalFolders=int(totfolders)
        self.update_progress()

        for x in range(50):
            totfolders-=1
            self.remainingFolders=totfolders
            self.update_progress()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI2App().run()
```

This is part of my kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0
<MyFloatLayout>:
    ProgressBar:
        id: loadingBar
        max: 0
        value: 1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.5}
        size_hint_x: 0.6
        size_hint_y: 0.1
    Button:
        text: "press me to change bar!"
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "y":0.6}
        size_hint_x: 0.6
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        on_press: app.initConcatenate()
```

### Error

It throws me this error:

```
in update_progress
     loadingBar= self.ids['loadingBar']
 KeyError: 'loadingBar'
```

### Extra Info

When I call the function it is called by another function in another class, to not get the error that one positional argument (self) is missing I call the function like this: "MyFloatLayout().update_progress()".

Idk if it helps but hopefully it does

Comment: What is the output for `print (self.ids)`?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur It gives me an empty set of brackets "{}" (I think it is an empty dictionary), why it's empty is now the question.

Comment: Your updated code ran on my device raising no error. Also you should change your current post's title (which should be meaningful and addresses the problem concisely).

Comment: What would you expect `MyFloatLayout().update_progress()` to do?

Comment: @wovano to update the max value, and the current value of the loading bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error that you mention, but there are some other errors in your code. The main error is in your code:

```
def update_progress(self):
    Clock.schedule_once(GUI2App.update_progress_after(self))
```

This code is running `GUI2App.update_progress_after(self)` and trying to schedule the returned result of that method, but the return is `None`. To correct this error, replace the above code with:

```
def update_progress(self):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.update_progress_after)
```

and add an `*args` argument to the `update_progress_after()` method definition:

```
def update_progress_after(self, *args):
```

Also, if you use:

```
MyFloatLayout().update_progress()
```

You are creating a new instance of `MyFloatLayout` and calling the `update_progress()` method of that new instance. But that new instance of `MyFloatLayout` is not the one that is in your `GUI`, so calling its `update_progress()` is likely to have no effect.